# Do nodes in a jboss cluster have their own db for persistent store?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, cluster-computing

Do entity beans in a cluster of nodes share the same data store?   Or can each node have its own database configured,  and the ejb layer takes care of replication and write to its own data store?   So that "joining" a cluster is a matter of getting the latest data from the cluster and then updating the local store with a write,  rather than trying to read from local store when joining?   And updates are replicated throughout,  and entities will write updates to local database?

Or does it just not work that way?  I have just been to jboss training and googled everywhere--probably because my question is too basic,  they could not answer my question in jboss class and nobody in any book or online has spelled it out.

Can the cluster be used as a reliable (and simple) means of replicating databases through entity beans?   I'm looking for a geographically distributed cluster with multiple data stores.   Or would this just be impossible (it's a distributed master-master replication problem,  if the entity ejb container is considered like a database).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The cluster replicates the application logic to make your application more scalable. It doesn't replicate the data store as this often implementation-specific.

The options for database clustering are many, and it depends largely on what you're using at the moment and what your objectives are from clustering - high availability, quick reads, quick writes, localised data, etc.